# Rows not aligned correctly in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for hours for the solution but didn't find.
Here is my HTML and CSS. I don't understand why the image 'THE_IMAGE.png' is not correctly aligned with the div above it ?

Can someone help me ? 
Thank you !
[image]

```css
body p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

body a:visited{
  color: white;
}


.page-header {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Actus */

#actus {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.section_title h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.button_all_actus {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  border-color: 1px solid white;
  height: 90px;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button_all_actus p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_2 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_2 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_3 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_3 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text_loin {
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.plus_loin {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section id ="actus">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>LOREM</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row all_actus">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>LOREM</h2>
      </div>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 button_all_actus">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a> 

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4  button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_3">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>

<section id="temoignages">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/THE_IMAGE.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what is your img size?

Comment: it's 242x242 pixels

Comment: you want the img in the middle? or?

Comment: No actually the menu below is aligned on the right and I can't align the image on the same line on the right, I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see, the image have `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px` which is from bootstrap.css here:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

just using `padding-right: 0;` is not enough, you need to use `padding-right: 0 !important;` to force it.

easy way to test is to add `background-color` to the images parent.
Or you can add `* { border: 1px solid red; }` to your css to quickly check block size of all element.

[image]

```css
body p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

body a:visited{
  color: white;
}

.divider_blue {
  border-top: 5px solid #0BB0DE;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.page-header {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Actus */

#actus {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.section_title h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.button_all_actus {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  border-color: 1px solid white;
  height: 90px;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button_all_actus p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_2 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_2 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_3 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_3 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text_loin {
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.plus_loin {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.alignright {
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 

<section id ="actus">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>Actus</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row all_actus">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>LOREM</h2>
      </div>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 button_all_actus">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a> 

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4  button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_3">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>

<section id="temoignages">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 alignright">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/242x242/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

put *class="img-responsive"* so it will fit the size of your parent div.

> **Explaination** 
>   img-responsive is a bootstrap classname that will automatically fit your image 100% width to your parent div. Example, if your parent div is 100px and the with of image is 500px, then your 500px image width will become same as 100px which is the width of the parent div (without resizing the document).
>
> More explainations here:
>
> https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/

I tried it on my PC and it's working.. See code below.

```
<section id="temoignages">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="section_title">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <hr class="divider_blue">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/THE_IMAGE.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

```css
body p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

body a:visited{
  color: white;
}

.divider_blue {
  border-top: 5px solid #0BB0DE;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.page-header {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Actus */

#actus {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.section_title h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.button_all_actus {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  border-color: 1px solid white;
  height: 90px;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button_all_actus p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_2 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_2 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button_actus_size_3 {
  background-color: #38C8D6;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
}

.button_actus_size_3 p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text_loin {
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.plus_loin {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 

<section id ="actus">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>Actus</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row all_actus">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>LOREM</h2>
      </div>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 button_all_actus">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a> 

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-4  button_actus_size_2">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 button_actus_size_3">
          <p class="text-left">LOREM</p>
          <p class="text-right"> &#8594; </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>

<section id="temoignages">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <hr class="divider_blue">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Ferdinand run the code above. Maximize the page. Is that what you want to?

Comment: Yes exactly ! @smzvax

Comment: Actually can you explain ?

Comment: I don't understand how you did it ?

Comment: Edited explaination Ferdinand

Comment: @Ferdinand but that does not seems to be the same line? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/4rjfves6/

Comment: I'm running Bootstrap 3... Unfortunately :(

Comment: @Daniel. that is already on same line . Just maximize the page. the jsfiddle is mobile size.

Comment: Not on my browser, I'm using Chrome

Comment: @Ferdinand are you sure? cus your img inside bootstrap col, unless you use !important to remove the 15px padding (left-right), it is always there, check the img in my post

Comment: @smzvax put this in your image's parent class `.redborder{ background-color: red; }` and you can see the padding at left and right